# How to write the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ as a polynomial in $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came a cross a question that gives a matrix $A$, and asks to write $A^{-1}$ as a polynomial in $A$ with real coefficients.

I don't know what this means, and googling didn't clarify very much. I found the inverse $A$, but I do not know what it means to write it as a polynomial in $A$.

Comment: What's the characteristic equation of $A$?

Comment: For example, you might write $A^{-1} = 8 I + (3/2) A + \pi A^2$.  The right side is a polynomial in $A$, i.e. a sum of finitely many coefficients times nonnegative powers of $A$ (with $A^0 = I$ the identity matrix), where the coefficients are real numbers.

Comment: Given a polynomial $$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$$ and a square matrix $A$, $f(A)$ is the matrix given by $$f(A) = a_0I + a_1A + \cdots + a_nA^n.$$

Comment: Let $\chi_A(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_n -A)$ be the 
[characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of $A$, [Cayley Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) says that $\chi_A(A) = 0$. When $\det A \ne 0$, you can rearrange $\chi_A(A) = 0$ to the form $A g(A) = I_n$ for some polynomial $g(\lambda)$, that means...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done for any invertible $A$ using the [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Determinant_and_inverse_matrix) that any matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation. If $a_i$ are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial then $a_0I + a_1A + \cdots + a_nA^n=0$ with $a_0=\det A$. Hence 
$$A^{-1}=-\frac1{a_0}(a_1I + \cdots + a_nA^{n-1}).$$

You can find the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition) by computing the determinant $\det(A-\lambda I)=a_0 + a_1\lambda + \cdots + a_n\lambda^n$.